# ImageView size relative to other layout

Tags: android, image, layout

I'm working on creating a header for my drawer in my current app. The problem is that I want to have a background image to it so I created a RelativeLayout and inserted an ImageView first and the the other layout.

I didn't put a background to the layout because it breaks everything.

My problem is that the image I want to put is really long and doesn't have a big height... I want the image height to fit the other layout's height and fit the width accordingly.

Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/draw_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/drawer_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_layout_texts"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.15">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_text_user"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/navigation_drawer_message_require_login"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:freezesText="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_text_club"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white_translucent"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:freezesText="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_text_handicap"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:freezesText="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/header_layout_texts"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can't understand properly

Comment: I want the ImageView `drawer_header` to be the same height as the `LinearLayout` `layout_header`

Comment: Put both of these layouts in another RelativeLayout and define the RelativeLayout's height some constant, and apply match_parent to the height of the layouts.